# Laravel queue / jobs sending request data

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am using laravel 5.4 
I have one problem and can't google it out.

Controller

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\TasksDownload;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\View\View; 
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Jobs\RequestTasksJob;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function requestTasks(Request $request)
    {
        dispatch(new \App\Jobs\RequestTasksJob([1,2]))
    }
}
```

App\Jobs\RequestTasksJob

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;

class RequestTasksJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $tasks;

    public function __construct(array $tasks)
    {
        $this-> tasks = $tasks;
    }

    public function handle()
    {
    }
}
```

And i am getting error :

> Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [  $tasks ]] in class App\Jobs\RequestTasksJob

Does anybody have solution? I am new in laravel.

Comment: Your `RequestTasksJob` class seems fine, so your error appears somewhere else where you are dispatching this job, you must be wrongly dispatching it, or you are not passing enough params to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously primitive parameter types are not allowed in Job constructors (at least in the new Laravel version). So use setter to pass the params ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add what is the `data type` of `$tasks` because Laravel can't `map` it into appropriate class if you don't provide it, so it fails to resolve the class it needs to map to.

Comment: it is array. When i send it as array $requestTasksJob->dispatch(['1', '2']) and define data type `(array $tasks)` i am getting following error `Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [ <required> array $carriers ]] `

Comment: Why are you `injecting` your job inside of a controller method?

Comment: `RequestTasksJob::dispatch($request->input('tasks'));` instead of `injecting` your job inside a controller method

Comment: I like injecting :) I have tried that too. but always getting `Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [ <required> array $carriers ]]`.

Only way i was able to pass it is to catch request direct from the job, and it creates new job in database but when i try to run it with php atisan it returns error because request dont exist any more.

Comment: Seems like you fixed the error `Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [ $tasks ]] in class App\Jobs\RequestTasksJob` and now you are getting other exception, can you tell me in which class does it pop that error now?

Comment: i have just added data type to constructor and error is changed because of that.
`at Container->unresolvablePrimitive(object(ReflectionParameter)) in Container.php line 826
    at Container->resolvePrimitive(object(ReflectionParameter)) in Container.php line 779
at Container->resolveDependencies(array(object(ReflectionParameter))) in Container.php line 747`

Comment: If it's a primitive type then you don't have to include it, read my initial answer, `Laravel can't map it into appropriate class` and `array` isn't an object but a primitive type

Comment: Which class throws this exception `Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [ <required> array $carriers ]]`

Comment: Job class \App\Jobs\RequestTasksJob trows it

Comment: Update your question with the full code of `\App\Jobs\RequestTasksJob` then